# Not getting desired path with gtk_tree_view_get_path_at_pos ()

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtktreeview

I have an application for which the user can open context menus inside a tree view. To get the current path after a right mouse click I use

`gtk_tree_view_get_path_at_pos (GTK_TREE_VIEW (treeview), event_button->x, event_button->y, &path, NULL, NULL, NULL)`, (event_button is of type *GdkEventButton*, which has been passed to the function)

which always reliably returns the correct path. I have ported my application to GTK4 now, where it is no longer possible to directly access the elements of an event. So I thought the way to go would be getting the coordinates by using

`gdk_event_get_coords (event, &x_win, &y_win)` (x_win and y_win are of type *double*)

and then

`gtk_tree_view_get_path_at_pos (GTK_TREE_VIEW (treeview), (gint) x_win, (gint) y_win, &path, NULL, NULL, NULL)`.

However, with the coordinates received by `gdk_event_get_coords` I always end up with the following path inside the tree view (x_win delivers the value as expected). How can I retrieve the same values as in GTK3?

Answer (score 0):

Using `gtk_tree_view_convert_widget_to_bin_window_coords` after `gdk_event_get_coords` does convert the original values to the expected results. The path is now the correct one.